# How to determine a larger type of a decltype expression

Tags: c++, c++11

Assume I have a function like this:

```
static const boost::int32_t SOME_CONST_VALUE = 1073741823;
template<typename targetType, typename sourceType>
targetType Convert(sourceType source)
{
    typedef decltype(source * SOME_CONST_VALUE) MulType_t;
    //typedef boost::int64_t MulType_t;
    MulType_t val = (MulType_t)source * (MulType_t)SOME_CONST_VALUE;
    return val / (MulType_t)SOME_CONST_VALUE;
}
```

When I call this function like this

```
boost::int32_t i = std::numeric_limits<boost::int32_t>::max();
boost::int32_t k = Convert<boost::int32_t>(i);
```

k equals 1, because of the overflow during the multiplication. Casting everything to `boost::int64_t` will lead to the result I want. But I don't want to cast a short or char to a int64 value.
So can I use the decltype to get the next larger type of the expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to make your own specialization of a template for that:

```
template<typename tp>
class bigger { }

template
class bigger<boost::int8_t>
{
    typedef boost::int16_t type;
}

template
class bigger<boost::int16_t>
{
    typedef boost::int32_t type;
}

template
class bigger<boost::int32_t>
{
    typedef boost::int64_t type;
}
```

You can also make a macro if you don't like typing alot:

```
#define BIGGER(x, y) \
    template \
    class bigger<boost::int##x##_t> \
    { \
        typedef boost::int##y##_t type; \
    }

BIGGER(8, 16);
BIGGER(16, 32);
BIGGER(32, 64);
```

and then use it like

```
bigger<boost::int32_t>::type x;
```

Comment: But that would be a lot of boilerplate code, because I would have to do this for every type I use. I was hoping that there would be a way with less typing.

Comment: @mkaes: How many integral types could there possibly be? They're all just typedefs of one another...

Comment: That is true. I am using boost::int8_t to int64_t and the same with boost::uint8_8 to uint64_t. So that would be 8 specializations.

Comment: @mkaes: I don't see 8.. there is 8,16,32,64.

Comment: @mkaes: you can use macro if you don't like typing, look at edit

Comment: @Dani: You forget signed and unsigned.

Comment: @ronag: there is a class in boost to remove unsigned, so you can do all this with one more line if you can use template aliases

Comment: @Dani: How would removing unsigned help? if you have uint8 you want uint16 (not int16) and if you have int8 you want int16.

Comment: @dani. 8 was a brainfart. And the macro solution is really nice. But for the sake of readability I will take the written version. Which is not as much as I thought.

Comment: @ronag: you can alias something like `unsigned bigger<remove_unsigned<T>>::type`

Comment: @Dani: I don't see how that helps in the OPs example, isn't it easier to just do the 6 specializations?

Answer (score 6):

Dani's answer has the right idea, but reinvents the wheel.
[Boost.Integer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/integer/index.html) was made to solve the problem of [integer type selection](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/integer.html).

```
static const boost::int32_t SOME_CONST_VALUE = 1073741823;
template<typename targetType, typename sourceType>
targetType Convert(sourceType source)
{
    typedef typename boost::int_t< 8 * sizeof( sourceType ) + 1 >::fast MulType_t;
    MulType_t val = static_cast<MulType_t>(source) * static_cast<MulType_t>(SOME_CONST_VALUE);
    return val / static_cast<MulType_t>(SOME_CONST_VALUE);
}
```

Not only are you avoiding new code (and new bugs), but you'll be using the *fastest* type for the operation you want.  If speed isn't what you're after Boost.Integer can also select the smallest type.